Возможно ли отобразить окно openCV на python в окне WPF c#?
есть программа на python с использованием cv2, которая распознаёт эмоцию человека через веб-камеру
в окне. Есть ли возможность отобразить это окно в окне WPF?

Я пытался сделать так, чтобы кадры сохранялись в отдельном файле, а потом доставались из этого файла уже в окно wfp, но у меня получалась ошибка доступа.

"Эмоции" - это вроде стандартное определение самого OpenCV, ну а он есть под C#. Теперь встречный вопрос - зачем вам прослойка в виде питона, если все это можно сделать на C#?

Я знаю, что есть способ сделать тоже самое на C#, но у меня уже есть готовый код на python, а переделывать его на C# или делать интерфейс на python не очень охота, поэтому пытаюсь как бы "соединить" wpf и python.
P.S. код там не маленький, поэтому переписывать это самая крайняя мера

Но зато самая надежная и самая правильная мера. Сейчас вы делаете огромный костыль, который только усложнит вам дальнейшую разработку. Да и что-то я сомневаюсь, что это возможно. Код питона вполнить да (IronPython), но чтоб окно...

Хорошо, я понял, спасибо!
